# awk parse data based on value in middle of text

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following input:

```
adm.cd.rrn.vme.abcd.name = foo
adm.cd.rrn.vme.abcd.test = no
adm.cd.rrn.vme.abcd.id = 123456
adm.cd.rrn.vme.abcd.option = no
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.name = bar
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.test = no
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.id = 324523
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.option = yes
adm.cd.rrn.vme.xxxx.name = blah
adm.cd.rrn.vme.xxxx.test = no
adm.cd.rrn.vme.xxxx.id = 666666
adm.cd.rrn.vme.xxxx.option = no
```

How can extract all the values associated with a specific id?
For example, if I have `id == 324523`, I'd like it to print the values of `name`, `test`, and `option`:

```
bar no yes
```

Is it possible to achieve in a single awk command (or anything similar in bash)?

EDIT: Based on input, here's my solution until now:

```
MYID=$(awk -F. '/'"${ID}"$'/{print $5}' ${TMP_LIST})
awk -F'[ .]' '{
                if ($5 == "'${MYID}'") {
                        if ($6 == "name")    {name=$NF}
                        if ($6 == "test")    {test=$NF}
                        if ($6 == "option")  {option=$NF}
                }
        } END {print name,test,option}' ${TMP_LIST})
```

Thanks

Comment: this is a bit complex since it needs to check above. What have you tried so far? Since you already asked around 20 questions in bash, you should be able to at least come up with something.

Comment: I can do it in 2 commands. First get the fifth column (`asfa`), then grep it and get the values I need. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to do with a single command to make it more effective.

Comment: Why does it matter how many question I ask? Is there a limit?

Comment: No, there is not a limit. However, you have asked questions enough to know that "homework" questions without any effort are unlikely to be very welcomed.

Comment: This is true if the questions are repetitive. I'm here to learn, not have you guys solve all my scripting issues.

Comment: @Maxim_united You say you can do it, so why not post what you already have as from your questions it does look like you are using this site as a coding service.

Comment: Never try to expand a shell variable as part of the body of an awk script (e,g, `"'${MYID}'"`) as it is fraught with dangers/caveats and will come back to bite you now or later. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
/option/ {
    if (rec ~ "id = "tgt"\n") {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
    next
}

$ awk -v tgt=324523 -f tst.awk file
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.name = bar
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.test = no
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.id = 324523
adm.cd.rrn.vme.asfa.option = yes
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[. ]" }
$(NF-2) == "id" { found = ($NF == tgt ? 1 : 0); next }
{ rec = (rec ? rec OFS : "") $NF }
$(NF-2) == "option" { if (found) print rec; rec = ""; next }

$ awk -v tgt=324523 -f tst.awk file
bar no yes
```

Answer (score 2):

first, I convert each record in a line with xargs, then I look for lines that contain the regular expression and print the columns searched

```
cat input | xargs -n 12 | awk '{if($0~/id\s=\s324523\s/){ print $3, $6, $12}}'
```

a solution more general:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\.|\\s"; } #field separator is point \\. or space \\s
{
  a[$5"."$6]=$8;           #store records in associative array a
  if($8=="324523" && $6=="id"){
    reg[$5]=1;             #if is record found, add to associative array reg
  }
}END{
  for(k2 in reg){
    s=""
    for(k in a){
      if(k~"^"k2"\\."){  #if record is an element of "reg" then add to output "s"
        s=k":"a[k]" "s
      }
    }
    print s;
  }
}' input
```

Comment: Hmm. that's a nice idea as well! But it requires me to know how many line of input I have in the first place. Or at least how many lines each unique "block" has.

Comment: 12 doesn't mean the number of lines .... is the number of "fields" ("words") in each record

Comment: Right, sorry. It means that each block must have 4 lines (3 words in each). What should I do if the number of lines varies ?

Comment: yep .... and order must be the same,  otherwise it should be done in different way

Comment: I appreciate your help. Can you please elaborate/explain the awk. (Yes I know it's complex:))

Comment: I'm curious - what do you think the single quotes are doing in `$8=='324523'`? You should mention that the solution is gawk-specific courtesy of `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

if your input format is fixed, you can do in this way:

```
grep -A1 -B2 'id\s*=\s*324523$' file|awk 'NR!=3{printf "%s ",$NF}END{print ""}'
```

you can add `-F'='` to awk part too.

it could be done by awk alone, but grep could save some typing...

Comment: That's a nice idea. However, I'm basing my script on some other command's output which I'm not sure won't change soon or later.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean. you can `otherCmd|grep ...|awk...` @Maxim_united

Comment: I mean that now it has a fixed format. I'm afraid it'll change sooner or later (from experience :) )

Comment: @Maxim_united then talk to your co-workers, ask what possibility the output format could be. otherwise, no solution will "always" work.